# Visual Studio Code devcontainer creation process hangs during final step

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm trying to create a new vscode, devcontainer for Python on OS X.

I went through the process to create a new devcontainer, selecting the defaults. When I hit OK to complete the process, the UI appears to be stuck on the final step--there is a blue bar that indicate progress, but it doesn't complete.  Docker Desktop indicates that the `python` volume has been created and has downloaded the `alpine` image.

I've tried to create other, devcontainers (R and PowerShell), but the problem occurs with these as well.

I have a postgres and mssql Docker containers working as expected.

I've tried restarting vscode and Docker Desktop, but the problem reoccurs.

Any suggestions?